# Aws RDS cpu Spike to 100% because of running set isolation command and set

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, isolation-level, amazon-rds-aurora

My application running with the AWS RDS as a backend.
currently i am doing a performance test.
While doing that i am seeing RDS cpu usage goes 100% after 20min.
While seeing the performance insights of the RDS i am seeing the below metrics,

[image]

and which shows setting the transaction isolation level are the culprit.
I have set the auto commit is false in my application. 
Please let me know why it causing these much spike. Do i need to configure any other stuffs to reduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are probably bogus.

If you have more than a few dozen connections, they will be stumbling over each other and everyone will progress very slowly.  Keep the number of threads to a realistic number.

`autocommit=0` should be outlawed.  It begs the programmer to forget to issue `COMMIT`.  Without `COMMIT`, a disconnect (or certain other things) will lead to a `ROLLBACK`.  Meanwhile, the connections may be blocking each other unnecessarily.

To discuss this further, let's see more details about the "performance test".